# Does pie graph / pie chart in adf has any limit on data?

Tags: oracle, pie-chart, oracle-adf

I have an page in adf which displays data in the form of a UI table and a pie graph. Both the components use the same query and VO.

But the problem is : the pie chart is not displaying all the data where in the UI table could display.

Can anyone tell me if there is any limit of data to represent in pie graph of adf?

Comment: try to change the rangesize of the iterator of the view object, used by the pie, to -1 (you do this from the databindings of the page the pie is on)

Comment: IMHO, it is better also to have a separate iterator for graphs with rangesize set to -1 as @MihaiC says.